# Win32 C++ Return cout Functionality From a Class

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I am working on a simple class so that if I use the cout "equivalent", it will display the console, if I don't, the console doesn't pop up.

The end result, if possible, trying to have something simple to use it, like: `O.C() << "any type of data";` OR `O.C("any type of data");` The equivalent of a `std::cout` stream. This side trip is so that I know it was used or not.

```
// the obvious, shows and opens a/the console window so I can use the cout and cin streams.
void ShowConsole() {
  AllocConsole();
  HANDLE handle_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  int hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long) handle_out, _O_TEXT);
  FILE* hf_out = _fdopen(hCrt, "w");
  setvbuf(hf_out, NULL, _IONBF, 1);
  *stdout = *hf_out;

  HANDLE handle_in = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long) handle_in, _O_TEXT);
  FILE* hf_in = _fdopen(hCrt, "r");
  setvbuf(hf_in, NULL, _IONBF, 128);
  *stdin = *hf_in;
}
```

From there, I am not sure what to do. The class I am writing defined globally as "O" for simplicity. The function `C()` is what I am trying to use to use the stream.

I don't know what to do here, either find a way to return a handle to cout with the `C()`, or find a way to let `C()` accept any type of data.

The class is basic, just looks like:

```
class testout {
private: 
    bool display;
public:
    void ShowConsole();
    void C(); // which could return a handle, or accept any data type
}
```

Any help is appreciated, I also probably used some incorrect terminology in spots.

Comment: [Variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: what does that have to do with accessing the console?

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought most console applications ran inside a console rather than choosing to create/destroy the only thing they live in.  A non-console app, would usually spawn a console app to display a console window.  (Or make something that looked like one with the GUI)  What I'm left with is why would it make sense to thoroughly open `stdout` and then replace the current `stdout` with what was retrieved?

Comment: My program is a Win32 application, and use GDI for the graphics. The program launches as the program itself, as any Win32 App would do. 

It is difficult to test out specific things without a console, where I can just "cout" any data, any type, any time. Which the way I currently have it, no problems at all. 

But what I am trying to do is create this class so that I can do the exact thing "cout" to the console, but I do not want the console to pop up if I have not sent anything to it.

It is a simple design, if I call the function "cout" equivalent, the shown bool is true. [CONT]

Comment: If I don't use the "cout" equivalent, the bool stays false and the ShowConsole() is not called. I am trying to do this because when I run the program, ShowConsole() is always called, and pops up, even when I have no use with it. I am really looking for the simplest way to go with this. Previously I just had a bool I set manually, but it gets a bit... old... always switching back and forth. **Best way to explain; I want the console to display if I use cout, and not display if I did not.**

Comment: have you considered to add tracing to your app. Then you can configure it when you want to see it or redirect it to a file.

Comment: I am not really sure what tracing is, but the console is really the only way to do it, so in real-time, I can see what values are, loop info, if something isn't working I know immediately. [Below] I found a workaround, I just overloaded a function to do the same thing, but with data types; it is functioning now, how I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

I figure that I might as well manually enter types.

```
void testout::TOUT(int i) {cout << i;}
void testout::TOUT(double d) {cout << d;}
void testout::TOUT(char c) {cout << c;}
void testout::TOUT(char* cstr) {cout << cstr; }
void testout::TOUT(string str) {cout << str; }
```

Within the class, to those functions I will additionally append updating shown to true.